# decoding 802.11 b

Tags: wifi, wireless, gnuradio

I have a raw grabbed data from spectrometer that was working on wifi (802.11b) channel 6.
(two laptops in ad-hoc ping each other).

I would like to decode this data in matlab. 
I see them as complex vector with 4.6 mln of complex samples.
I see their spectrum quite nice. I am looking document a bit less complicated as IEEE 802.11 standard (which I have).

I can share measurement data to other people.

Comment: @Jonas: IEEE 802.11b is the old wireless comms standard, so [tag:wireless] seems to be pretty relevant here.

Comment: well post was made 14 years ago..... 802.11n was not even existing :-). Anyway i made the PhD passive coherent location using WIFI. Today WIFI is using much more bandwidth giving better resolution etc... (probably gives possibility a small size swarm of to detect mosquitos over the pong in the garden) however writing a code to decode newest WIFI that might be huge challenge

Answer (score 1):

There's now a few solutions around for decoding 802.11 using Software Defined Radio (SDR) techniques. As mentioned in a previous answer there is software that is based on gnuradio - specifically there's [gr-ieee802-11](http://www.ccs-labs.org/software/gr-ieee802-11/) and also [802.11n+](http://nms.citi.sinica.edu.tw/n+/software.html). Plus the higher end SDR boards like [WARP](http://warpproject.org/trac) utilise FPGA based implementations of [802.11](http://warpproject.org/trac/wiki/802.11). There's also a bunch of implementations of 802.11 for Matlab available e.g. [802.11a](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3540-ieee-802-11a-wlan-model).

Answer (score 0):

If your data is really *raw* then you basically have to build every piece of the signal processing chain in software, which is possible but not really straightforward. Have you checked the relevant [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio)? You might use [gnuradio](http://gnuradio.org/) instead of starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I have used 802.11 IEEE standard to code and decode data on matlab.
Coding data is an easy task.
Decoding is a bit more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Stan, it is going to be tough doing everything yourself. you may get some ideas from the projects on CGRAN like :

https://www.cgran.org/wiki/WifiLocalization